# Internet Explorer 8 Settings File Location

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

I frequently use a web site which has been designed specifically for Internet Explorer 8. What's more, I need to adjust a few dozen settings in IE8 for the site to function correctly. The problem is that, every month or two or three, my settings will get reset to the default IE8 settings.

**Is there a file saved somewhere by IE that stores the setting options I've selected?** I'd love to be able to just make a backup copy of that file and then just paste it back in when the settings get messed up. The settings I change are found in Internet Options > Security > Custom Level and Internet Options > Advanced.

I'm using 64-bit Windows 7. I have my Windows updates installing automatically, so I'm not sure if Microsoft is still releasing IE8 updates that may be causing the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These settings are saved in the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones`. After configuring your settings, you can export the registry keys for later use.

Each key under Zones corresponds to a zone in your IE settings:

1. Local intranet
2. Trusted sites
3. Internet
4. Restricted sites

You may want to consider adding this website to trusted sites instead of modifying your Internet zone. Otherwise you may be opening yourself up to malware.

As for the advanced options, those are stored under 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\AdvancedOptions\`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tanner. I backed up the keys, messed up the settings in IE, then restored the registry. It restored the IE settings under Security > Custom Level, but not the "Advanced" Settings. I tried it first with exporting just the Zones folder, and then again with exporting the entire Internet folder (and rebooted after restoring the registry), and the result was the same. Any other ideas?

Comment: Found the advanced settings! If you only want to backup a handful of those, check which registry keys change using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

Comment: I was able to restore settings using the Zones folder just fine, but when I do the same thing for the AdvancedOptions folder, nothing restores. I tried narrowing it to the Accessibility folder and then to the AltText folder (with just toggling the first Advanced setting in IE8) and still no luck. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score -1):

Type in the path '%AppData%', than go into the Roaming\Microsoft\  folder. I think it is somewhere there, not sure about it.

Hope it helps.